# Pipreqs outputs 2 versions of the same package

Tags: python, pip, sqlalchemy

I updated SQLAlchemy to the latest version, but now when i use pipreqs to build my requirement.txt file, it outputs two versions of SQLAlchemy despite me only having one installed:

```
boto3==1.34.39
pandas==1.5.3
psycopg2==2.9.9
Requests==2.31.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.39
SQLAlchemy==2.0.28
```

I tested it out and literally if I just import SQLAlchemy it builds a req file with both versions - I have no idea what is going on, I check my local SQLAlchemy version which is 2.0.28. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Find the `site-packages` directory (maybe with `python -m site`), and look inside if there is more than one `.dist-info` directory for SQLAlchemy.

Comment: There is one titled: "sqlalchemy" and one titled "SQLAlchemy-2.0.28.dist-info", could that be the issue?

Comment: OK, then no, that is not the cause of the issue. It is the expected case to have those two directories for each installation of SQLAlchemy (or any other library/package). -- You could expand your search to other directories listed in `python -m site`, see if there is any trace of `SQLAlchemy 1.4.9` somewhere.

Comment: There is just a bunch of anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',  "anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', \\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', etc. but there is no SQLAlchemy in any of them that i can find

Comment: I do not know how to help then. -- I do not know how *pipreqs* works internally. -- You might want to ask the maintainers directly: https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/issues -- There is this issue ticket already (maybe related): https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/issues/434

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is super frustrating and strange